# .Net Mvc 3 Trigger (other than submit button) Unobtrusive Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation, unobtrusive-validation

**What I would Like**

I would like to trigger client-side validation in my View with an event of my choice.  It could be 'onblur' maybe another button but something other than the submit button.

**Relevant Links**

[How to trigger validation without using a submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785510/how-to-trigger-validation-without-using-a-submit-button)

[Applying unobtrusive jquery validation to dynamic content in ASP.Net MVC](http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content)

**What I've tried**

Given a various event listener, I've fired the following methods with no luck:

`$(selector).validate();`

`$(selector).valid();`

`$.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent(selector);`

`$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(selector));`

**Summary**

So I need client-side validation to fire on a given event (other than on submit) and show the corresponding validation messages.  I dont feel like any of the Markup/Razor syntax is necessary as client-validation fires on submit and all the corresponding validation messages show as expected.

Comment: I posted something too that worked [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479255/how-to-manually-trigger-validation-with-jquery-validate/13134434#13134434

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`$('form').valid()` should work. Let's exemplify.

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Foo)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Foo)
}

<div id="validate">Hover here to trigger validation</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#validate').hover(function () {
        $('form').valid();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This worked a treat for me, though I had even more success when I changed the EditorFor to TextBoxFor so that I could give it a css class.

Answer (score 1):

Manual validation of custom messages injected directly to HTML

```
@{using (Html.BeginForm("addBuyOnlinepostA", "BuyOnline", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "form1" }))
  {

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            Product Qty
            <input class="inputs" required type="number" id="price" name="price" placeholder="Enter Price in AED"
                data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter a value" data-val-regex="Please enter a valid number."
                data-val-regex-pattern="\d{1,20}" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="price" data-valmsg-replace="true"
                style="color: Red;"></span>
        </div>
    </div>   



    <input type="button" onclick="$('form').valid()" />

  }
}
```