# asp.net mvc 3 unobstrusive validation issue

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I'm trying to make some Category entity adding form with unobstrusive validation on client side.

Here is my entity:

```
public class Category
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Alias")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Have to complete")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "asdasdasd", MinimumLength = 3)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Name1")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Have to complete")]
    public String DisplayName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Name2")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Have to complete")]
    public String DisplayNameTZK { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Url")]
    [DataType(DataType.Url, ErrorMessage = "Url")]
    public String Uri { get; set; }

    public Guid AddingGuid { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }

   ...
}
```

Here is my view:

```
@model HSDT.Models.Entities.Category

@{
    Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript();
    Html.EnableClientValidation();
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("", "", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "addCategoryForm", name = "addCategoryForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Category</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisplayName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisplayNameTZK)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayNameTZK)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayNameTZK)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Uri)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Uri)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Uri)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddingGuid)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddingGuid)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddingGuid)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsActive)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Now I left all my inputs emty and tried to validate this form to get the errors shown in my model using:

```
$("#addCategoryForm").validate().valid()
```

But I get `true`(and no errors) as a result, but should be `false` because in the data annotation I added `[Required]` attribute for few fields. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any advance.

**EDIT-1**

Here is my config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

Here is references:

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: why are you calling `$("#addCategoryForm").validate().valid()`? the submit of the form should validate the input's. Or is there some missing js in the question?

Comment: I'm opening my site in google chrome and write it in the console

Comment: I think your js is wrong try `$("#addCategoryForm").valid()`

Comment: It appears you can't fire this direct from js. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301492/net-mvc-3-trigger-other-than-submit-button-unobtrusive-validation. You need to actually submit the form

Comment: sorry, that statement is wrong, thats what you get for replying before going on lunch...you can and .valid() is the way to do it. Could be the console doesn't fire it correctly.

Comment: console is fire correctly. (((

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31164/discussion-between-maris-and-liam)

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the js-files in the correct order?

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And in webconfig:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: All the reference was added!

Comment: Do you have something like "if(ModelState.IsValid)" in postback action so the validation is executed?

Comment: I didn't do any request to server-side. The problem is in client-side-validation.

Comment: what if you use: @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "div-outside-form-id"  }))

Comment: I dont want to use server-side validation! I want that my data being validated in the client side using unobstructive validation

Answer (score -1):

Remove the following from your view

```
$("#addCategoryForm").validate().valid()
Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript();
Html.EnableClientValidation();
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

Add the following js-files to your view :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Use

```
<button type="submit">Create</button>
```

in place of

`<input type="submit" value="Create" />`

Add the Web-config part as described by @Lasse .
This will lead you to model validation throwing validation error if any.

Comment: I want to submit form though the Ajax not the simple form submitting!

Comment: I want to call the jquery validation anywhere!

Comment: @Maris can you be more specific about your issue related to ajax?

Comment: I have the form I want:
1) Validate the data though the Jquery
2) If there is some errors -> display the errors
3) If there is no errors -> submit the data using $.post(...).

<input type="submit"> - will refresh the whole page, but I dont want to do it!